# Put Android Studio application in sub-folder in Git

Tags: android, git, gradle

I have repository in Git that has this structure:

```
-web-app
-mobile-app
```

When I checkout the project in Android Studio my project has structure like this:

```
 android-studio-project
    -web-app
    -mobile-app
```

The mobile-app folder is folder that contains the module of my android application end when I commit some changes some files and folders like gradle/wrapper, build.gradle, gradle.properties, settings.gradle are outside the folder mobile-app and my Git structure goes like this:

```
  android-studio-project
    -web-app
    -mobile-app
    -gradle/wrapper
    -build.gradle
    -gradle.properties
    -settings.gradle
    -...
```

I want to put all files and mobile-app folder in sub-folder in order to achieve first Git structure. 
I tried to create a folder in Android Studio and move all needed files there but the project totally messed up.
I moved the gradle's files in to mobile-app folder but could not build the project at all.

Any ideas how can achieve the desired Git structure?

Comment: I'm not sure your problem necessarily has anything to do with Git, rather that you created a project structure which Gradle/Android can't build.  You should stick to the standard Gradle project layout unless there is a burning reason to do otherwise.

Comment: The application owner wants everything for mobile app to be in one folder in the Git repository and everything for web-app in another and no other files outside of those folders. I explained that he want is a bull sh** but ... he want it that way. I can remove those files from Git and put them in gitignore but ... it is not a good idea.

Comment: I am actually wrapping up an Android app at the moment, which uses a Java webapp in the cloud, so I sort of can relate to your problem.  Why not just add the source and build folders under a single parent folder, or am I missing something?  The webapp could be a third folder there.

Comment: I am sorry but I could not understand what you are offering. As long I understand for my case, you offer to move web-app folder outside the android-studio-project or I assume wrong?

Comment: No what I'm saying is what's stopping you from just versioning things ths way they already are?  Just use a parent folder and then add the webapp.  I agree with you, by the way.  Nothing wrong with the webapp being in a completely separate repo.

Comment: I tried to make a folder and move module and gradle files and folders there but the project did not build after that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167046/discussion-between-dimdim-and-tim-biegeleisen).